# PLSQL - convert unix timestamp with millsecond precision to timestamp(6)

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a unix timstamp with millsecond precision like below:

```
1523572200000
```

I need to convert it to timestamp(6). This is the format I need:

```
05-NOV-14 09.45.00.000000000 AM
```

(Fyi examples above are not matching dates, just using as example.)

What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that current timestamp is: 1523572200000, try following:

```
select cast (to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 1523572200000/1000/60/60/24 as timestamp) from dual;
```

where:

- `to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` is epoch time
- `<unix_timestamp>/60/60/24` was divided by 1000 miliseconds 60 second and 60 minutes and 24 hours because in oracle we are adding **days**

Answer (score 1):

The following might work for you (where `myunixtimestamp` is the name of the column in which your Unix timestamps are stored):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(myunixtimestamp/1000, 'SECOND')
  FROM mytable;
```

For example,

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(1523572200000/1000, 'SECOND')
  FROM dual;
```

gives a result of `2018-04-12 10:30:00.000000000 PM`.

Hope this helps.